# Generating i.i.d samples in MATLAB: large p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, uniform-distribution, iid

I'm trying to generate i.i.d samples from two uniformly distributed random variables in MATLAB. However, when I correlate the two sets of samples, I find that the correlation is almost zero, but the p-value is above 0.05. How should I interpret this test? Is it even possible to generate i.i.d samples in real life?

```
>> [r,p] = corrcoef(rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000))

r =

    1.0000   -0.0508
   -0.0508    1.0000


p =

    1.0000    0.1082
    0.1082    1.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of the p value: it is the probability of observing a test statistic as extreme as the one you observed or more extreme under the null hypothesis.

Or, looking at this under a slightly different angle: If your null hypothesis holds, then your p value is a random variable *that is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$*.

Try this. Re-run your code and note the p values you get. Make a histogram. You should get a flat histogram with a uniform distribution.

One consequence is that "small" and "large" p values will occur equally often under the null hypothesis. For instance, you should see a $p<0.05$ and a $p>0.95$ each about in one in twenty cases.

Another consequence is that *you shouldn't expect large p values if your null hypothesis holds*. What you should expect is $U[0,1]$-distributed p values. Unfortunately, this is rather hard to observe if all you have is a single realization, i.e., a single p value.

[The dance of the p values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1RqHrZQ8) is a short and very enlightening video that may be helpful.